# Relation chain in prolog

Tags: prolog

```
father(Father,Child).
mother(Mother,Child).

{ father(Raja,Raj), mother(Rani, Roop) }
```

In relation database how to answer questions like- **“How is X related to Y?”**,
Eg - how to write rule for "How Raj is related to Raja" , so that answer would be Raja is Raj's father.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to help, introducing what I think are the useful builtin predicates.
But first, we should agree about the **database** term. The most needed specification is about **modules**: in SWI-Prolog all predicates live in some module, but we could simply ignore this feature, and go for unqualified binary relations - as from your example.

After you start SWI-Prolog, you can see how many predicates are defined running

```
?- aggregate(count,X^current_predicate(X),N).
N = 1034.
```

and to get only binary relations

```
?- aggregate(count,X^current_predicate(X/2),N).
N = 371.
```

Your actual values most probably will be different. Now let's enter your database' facts, just quoting the **atoms** (otherwise we have variables, or better, singletons):

```
?- [user].
father('Father','Child').
|: mother('Mother','Child').
|: ^Dtrue.
```

Now

```
?- aggregate(count,X^current_predicate(X/2),N).
N = 373.
```

as expected, there are two more binary predicates.

Now, clause/2 will answer your question:

```
?- V='Child', current_predicate(R/2), C=..[R,U,V], clause(C,B), call(B).
V = 'Child',
R = father,
C = father('Father', 'Child'),
U = 'Father',
B = true ;
V = 'Child',
R = mother,
C = mother('Mother', 'Child'),
U = 'Mother',
B = true
```

So far, we've found that both father/2 and mother/2 are valid relations having 'Child' as right argument. Alas, a further backtracking raises an (unexpected) error:

```
...
U = 'Mother',
B = true ;
ERROR: No permission to access private_procedure `(is)/2'
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] clause(_7524 is 'Child',_7520)
ERROR:    [8] '<meta-call>'(user:(...,...)) <foreign>
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

and, again alas, predicate_properties/2 seems broken, so I cannot think right now about the proper way to avoid the error...

Comment: BTW; `library(aggregate)` comes originally from O'Keefe @ Quintus, so you find it in SICStus, too.